# Why request.body is empty on call custom API using tastypie?

Tags: python, django, api, swagger, tastypie

Facing issue with POST API call. I am using tastypie `prepend_urls` `wrap_view` for login custom api.
I am using below versions: 
**Tastypie 0.14.3** 
 
**Tastypie_swagger 0.1.4** 
 
**Django 2.2.12** 
 
**Python 3.5.2**

I am using below deserialize method to abstract data from payload. I don't know why I'm getting empty request.body.

```
data = self.deserialize(
            request, request.body,
            format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
        )
```

If I'm trying to convert request data into json, Then it is raising Request is not valid JSON. As per my debugging it is using **package method** named  deserialize and into `serialize.py` of **tastypie**. It is using from_json method.
Also request.body returning blank query dict. I am receiving data which is passing into POST call with request.GET. Is it happening due to upgraded version of python and tastypie?
Is there something am I doing wrong? 
Here is some output of my request. It would be helpful to understand the scenario. 
I am getting this **params into GET instead of request.body**.

```
request.GET
<QueryDict: {'username': ['abc@gmail.com'], 'password': ['123456']}>
```

**Empty POST QueryDict**

```
request.POST
<QueryDict: {}>
```

**Request call:**

```
request
<WSGIRequest: POST '/api/v1/user/login/?username=abc%40gmail.com&password=123456'>
```

```
self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
'post'
```

```
request.body
b''
```

It should have JSON payload like `{"username":"password"}`. Please suggest me what should I do for resolved below error.

```
{
  "status": "0",
  "message": "Request is not valid JSON."
}
```

Thanks in advance!!